# How relevant are url names in non english speaking countries?

Tags: seo, internationalization, search-engine

If I have a commercial site belonging to a Japanese company which will use Katakana or Kanji *(non ASCII characters)* for the keyword they wish to obtain good search results in google, does it still matter to put the closest english word on the site DNS Name?

like:

if the search word is "homepage" in Katakana: ホームページ

Will the the DNS name have an impact on the results?

Is it better, does it have any effect having a DNS Name which includes "homepage"?

Thanks,
Ric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What name will bring higher hit counts is kind of an art, not a science.
Since the IDN (International Domain Names) support is still weak in a lot of tools I would think that a Japanese DNS name would bring less hits than an English one.

On another side, in my experience the content and proper tagging of the content is way-way more important than the domain name itself to attract traffic.

Answer (score 0):

DNS international domains are translated to unreadable ascii, so I guess it doesn't make sense to use it for SEO.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am asking the direct opposite: I would like to know if text "homepage-dot-something" in ASCII has an effect on the non ASCII google: ホームページ search